# Hadoop2.4.0 creating 39063 Map tasks to process 10MB file in Local mode with invalid Inputsplit configuration

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

am using hadoop-2.4.0 with all default configuration expect below:

```
FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, new Path("in")); //10mb file;  just one file.

FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path("out"));

job.getConfiguration().set("mapred.max.split.size", "64");

job.getConfiguration().set("mapred.min.split.size", "128");
```

PS: I set max split size is lesser than min(Initially I set by mistake and I realized)

And, as per inputsplit calucaiton logic

```
max(minimumSize, min(maximumSize, blockSize))
```

`max(128,min(64,128) --> 128MB` and it is great than file size, so it should create only one inputsplit(one mapper)

Am just curious about how the framework calculating **39063** mappers each time when I run this program in eclipse?

**Logs:**

```
2015-07-15 12:02:37 DEBUG LocalJobRunner Starting mapper thread pool executor.

2015-07-15 12:02:37 DEBUG LocalJobRunner Max local threads: 1

2015-07-15 12:02:37 DEBUG LocalJobRunner Map tasks to process: 39063

2015-07-15 12:02:38 INFO  LocalJobRunner Starting task: 
attempt_local192734774_0001_m_000000_0
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code you have specified:

```
job.getConfiguration().set("mapred.max.split.size", "64");

job.getConfiguration().set("mapred.min.split.size", "128");
```

Its calculating into bytes. Hence you are getting high number of Mapper.

I think you should use something like this:

```
job.getConfiguration().set("mapred.min.split.size", 67108864);
```

67108864 is value in bytes of 64MB

Calculation: `64*1024*1024 = 67108864`

`mapred.max.split.size` is basicall used to combine small file to defint split size where you are dealing with large number of small files and `mapred.min.split.size` is used to define split where you are dealing with  large files.

If you are using YARN or MR2 then you should use `mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.minsize`

Comment: That gave me java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "128*1024*1024" ;
And,
I tried below, seems it worked.   

job.getConfiguration().set("mapred.max.split.size", "67108864");
job.getConfiguration().set("mapred.min.split.size", "134217728");